# HoloViews: create boxplots for every column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, bokeh, holoviews

I'm able to create the following boxplot with Pandas [pandas.DataFrame.boxplot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4),
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])

df.plot.box()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Although, if I try to do the same using HoloViews' [BoxWhisker Element](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/BoxWhisker.html#elements-bokeh-gallery-boxwhisker) with Bokeh as backend, it works fine for a single column:

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')

hv.BoxWhisker(
    data=df['Col1'],
    vdims='Col1'
)
```

[image]

But as soon as I try to add just another column, I get the below error:

```
hv.BoxWhisker(
    data=df[['Col1', 'Col2']]
)

DataError: None of the available storage backends were able to support the supplied data format. PandasInterface raised following error:

 unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

PandasInterface expects tabular data, for more information on supported datatypes see http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Tabular_Datasets.html
```

I can't understand whether there is a problem with the [Tabular Data](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Tabular_Datasets.html) HoloViews understands, or I'm not able to apply the syntaxis properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would also recommend James Bednar's answer,** which is using [hvPlot](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/reference/pandas/box.html#gallery-box). HvPlot is built on top of HoloViews:

```py
import hvplot.pandas
df.hvplot.box()
```

**However, if you want to do it in HoloViews instead of hvPlot, you would have to [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) your data** to get all column names in one column, and all values in the other column.

**This code works for your sample data:**

```py
hv.BoxWhisker(df.melt(), kdims='variable', vdims='value')
```

Comment: As mentioned to @james, I was able to make it work after "transforming" my data in the same way you did (i.e. from wide to long format). The only difference is that I used `pd.wide_to_long()` instead of `pd.melt()`.

Comment: Is your recommendation related to this specific example, or do you think **hvPlot** should be used instead of straight **HoloViews** as much as possible? Are there known limitations in hvPlot that forces you to fall back to HoloViews?

Comment: I almost always use hvPlot instead of HoloViews, especially when doing quick data analysis. There's probably usecases where HoloViews is better, but I find hvPlot just nice and easy to use, especially when you have multiple columns, no need to do any melting etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to achieve what you want from the native HoloViews BoxWhisker interface, which is set up for tidy data rather than a set of independent columns like that.  Meanwhile you can use hvPlot just as you use the native .plot() call:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about **hvPlot** API, thanks for that. What you've mentioned about "tidy data" led me to investigate a little bit more in the **HoloViews** docs, mainly the section about [Tabular Datasets](http://holoviews.org/getting_started/Tabular_Datasets.html), and eventually I was able to make it work without `df.hvplot.box()`, after transforming the data from "wide" to "long" format.